# Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: No WebApplication provider is present

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, jersey

I am new to spring and trying to run an simple example from
[This link](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jax-rs/create-a-simple-restful-web-service-using-jersey-jax-rs/)while running CalcRESTStartUp.java which contains.

```
package com.theopentutorials.jaxrs.calc;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory;
public class CalcRESTStartUp {

    static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:9999/calcrest/";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create(BASE_URI);
            server.start();
            System.out.println("press enter");
            System.in.read();
            server.stop(0);
             }catch(IllegalArgumentException e ){
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }catch(IOException e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
    }

}
```

I am getting exception Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: No WebApplication provider is present. Exception details.

> INFO: Root resource classes found:
>         class com.theopentutorials.jaxrs.calc.CalcREST
>         class org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.internal.WadlResource
>       Mar 01, 2015 2:10:43 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
>       INFO: No provider classes found.
>       Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: No WebApplication provider is present
>           at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationFactory.createWebApplication(WebApplicationFactory.java:69)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:160)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:264)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:246)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:117)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:92)
>           at com.theopentutorials.jaxrs.calc.CalcRESTStartUp.main(CalcRESTStartUp.java:11)

please help me. Thanks in advance